# How to apply a simple filter with Flink in Scala

Tags: scala, filter, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I was using an old version of Flink. I upgrade to 1.2.0 and I have some issues with filters.

I have a DataStream of Log which works just fine :

```
 val logs: DataStream[Log] = env.addSource(new LogSource(
      data, delay, factor))

 // DISPLAY TUPLE IN CONSOLE
 logs.print()

 // EXECUTE SCRIPT
 env.execute("stream")
```

I have of course read the documentation which shows :

```
dataStream.filter { _ != 0 }
```

I tried a bunch of things like this :

```
val cleanLogs = logs.filter { _.isComplete }
```

But I got the following error :

> Type mismatch, expected: FilterFunction[Log], actual: (Any) => An

So I don't see the link between the documentation and this error.
Any help ? Examples ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the signature of the `isComplete` method?

Comment: It is not a method, the first attribute of Log is a boolean : isComplete. It worked perfectly fine with Flink 0.10, but it may not be possible anymore ?

Comment: I can't really reproduce your problem. The only thing that comes to my mind are some wrong imports. Make sure you are importing the scala versions of `DataStream` and `StreamExecutionEnvironment`. It is best in scala to always import `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._`

Comment: I think you're right, `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._` is said "unused" by my IDE. I will look into it

Comment: It came from my import of `StreamExecutionEnvironment` indeed, now I have to figure out the problem with `LocalStreamEnvironment`, anyway I am closer of the solution thanks to you.

Comment: Always happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was first a wrong import of `StreamExecutionEnvironment` which lead to this problem with basic functions like `filter`.

Then as I used an old version of Flink I was using `LocalExecutionEnvironment` class which is no longer available in Flink 1.X.

Instead : `StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(1)`